# Question about an example of 'simply connected' region if two homotopic curves have the same end-point(stein and shakarchi)

Tags: complex-analysis

Shakarchi gives an example of a simply connected region and one that is not simply connected as follows.
Simply connected:
[image: page1]

And a region not simply connected:
[image: page2]

My question is for the simply connected region:

1. I understand that the curves are homotopic with the same end points so they are simply connected.The only question there is shouldn't $|\theta_{j}| \leq \pi/2$ rather than $|\theta_{j}| <= \pi$ since we are considering the region after the positive real axis?
2. Also, this region does not include the origin, according to the definition of the slit plane. So, shouldn't be non-homotopic just as it says in the example about not simply connected region. That region doesn't include the origin which makes it non-homotopic?

That is why I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The polar angle $\theta$ measures the angle starting at the positive real axis, so $\theta=0$ describes the positive real axis, while $\theta=\pm\pi$ describes the negative real axis. Since we want to remove the negative real axis, we should require the restriction $\theta\neq\pm\pi$. And given that $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$ anyway, this results in $\vert\theta\vert<\pi$.
2. Missing the origin is not what makes the punctured plane non-simply connected. It's missing the origin *and nothing else* that makes it non-simply connected. Basically, the difference is that in the punctured plane we can draw a circle around the origin, while in the slit plane we can't, because there's an entire line extending from the origin which we're not allowed to cross with our circle. The question isn't "is this point missing?", but rather "can we go around the missing point?"

Comment: I din't understand what you said about an entire line extending from the origin in the slit plane. The slit plane does not include the origin either. It is ${\Bbb{C} -{-\infty, 0}}$.

Comment: Also, about point 1 above, it would be more accurate to say $|\theta \leq \pi/2|$ rather than $|\theta < \pi|$.

Comment: $(-\infty,0]$ is a line extending from the origin to the left. That line includes the origin, so yes, the origin is missing from the slit plane. But so does the entire rest of the line, which is the important part. Also, $\vert\theta\vert\leq\pi/2$ describes the closed right half plane, not the slit plane. For instance, $-1+\mathrm i$ has a polar angle of $3\pi/4>\pi/2$, while still being in the slit plane.

Comment: Thank you so much @Vercassivelaunos!! That helped. Now, if I understand the slit plane, I could pick for one of end points of $\gamma$ a point $\not\in {\Bbb{C}-{0, -\infty}}$ and similarly for the other end point and I would have a simply connected region. I also thought about curves that lie say have beginning and end points one in the upper left half and the other in the lower left half - but that is not possible, since the line ${{-\infty - 0}}$ does not allow it.